# Sorting 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ios

I have the following case. I import data from an xml feed and from facebook graph api, in this case posts. I want to merge this data in a array and sort this on the included date data.

I have now the following:

```
[containerArray addObject: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: created_time, message, picture, fbSource, nil ]
                    ];
```

This creates a 2-dimensional array, but i want to order all the entries on created_time.

How can i best solve this problem? Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a data class containing the necessary instance variables instead of the mutable array. Then you can use the various sort method of the NSArray class, for example [`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCJGCJI).

A sort could look like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_time" 
                                                                ascending:YES] autorelease];    

NSArray *sortedArray = [containerArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

[sortDescriptor release];
```

**EDIT**

To quote Mr. Fowler from his book [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring).

> **Replace Array with Object**
>
> You have an array in which certain elements mean different things.
>
> *Replace the array with an object that has a field for each element*
>
> ...
>
> **Motivation**
>
> Arrays are a common structure for organizing data. However, they should be used only to contain a collection of similar objects in somre order.

That's what we want to do here. Let's create a simple Posts class. You can easily add your custom initializer which accepts the four values as parameters, or even a convenience class method to return an autoreleased object later on. This is just a basic skeleton:

### Post.h

```
@interface Posts : NSObject 
{
    NSDate *created_time; 
    NSString *message;
    UIImage *picture;
    id fbSource; // Don't know what type :)
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *created_time;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *picture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id fbSource;

@end
```

### Post.m

```
#import "Post.h"

@implementation Post

@synthesize created_time, message, picture, fbSource;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark memory management

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [created_time release];
    [message release];
    [picture release];
    [fbSource release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark initialization

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // do your initialization here
    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding a Post object to your array:

```
Post *newPost = [[Post alloc] init];
newPost.reated_time = [Date date];
newPost.message = @"a message";
newPost.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mypic.jpg"];
// newPost.fbSource = ???
[containerArray addObject:newPost];

[newPost release];
```

Comment: So I shouldn't use the mutable array to store the data. Instead I need to create a data class, but what exactly is this data class? Is this NSData? I'm not that experienced with objective-c. Thnx!

Comment: Wow Nick, thnx for the extensive answer! Though i'm not sure how to integrate this in my code. I accepted your answer because it do gives an answer to my initial question, but i'm may get back at ya! Thnx

Comment: Hello Nick, for the moment i'm busy with integrating your solution in my code. I've created the Post class with the instances and the convenience method in the, in my case, NewsTable class. So far so good, but how do I set al my instances (like created time, message, etc)? In my initial post you see the way how i'm currently setting them. Thnx again!

Comment: @Jos added a simple example in Edit2. With a convenience class method you could create an autoreleased object and add it directly to your array.